# JFileChooser application running as a service

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I'm having an issue with `JFileChooser`, when I'm running my application as a service (I'm using geronimo), file chooser doesn't work, I don't see my popup.

```
JFileChooser chooser = null;
System.out.println("chooser " + chooser) // chooser is not equals null
```

It crashes with `JFileChooser`.

Comment: Not 100% sure, hence the comment however I do not think that services can have GUI components. Maybe someone kind enough to clarify.

Comment: Check that your service is not started with in headless mode (-Djava.awt.headless=true)

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
JFileChooser jf = new JFileChooser(System.getProperty("user.dir"));// opening for current directory
jf.showOpenDialog(this); // For popup the filechooser window
```